# How do I get the stepContext from the PromptValidator in Microsoft Bot Framework?

Tags: c#, botframework

I am working with the [DialogPromptBot sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-prompts?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp). In the sample there is the following code:

```
// Create the dialog set and add the prompts, including custom validation.
_dialogSet = new DialogSet(_accessors.DialogStateAccessor);
_dialogSet.Add(new NumberPrompt<int>(PartySizePrompt, PartySizeValidatorAsync));
_dialogSet.Add(new ChoicePrompt(LocationPrompt));
_dialogSet.Add(new DateTimePrompt(ReservationDatePrompt, DateValidatorAsync));

// Define the steps of the waterfall dialog and add it to the set.
WaterfallStep[] steps = new WaterfallStep[]
{
    PromptForPartySizeAsync,
    PromptForLocationAsync,
    PromptForReservationDateAsync,
    AcknowledgeReservationAsync,
};
_dialogSet.Add(new WaterfallDialog(ReservationDialog, steps));
```

It sets up some prompts, validates the user's input and saves their responses. I don't like the way the code works because the user's input is saved in the next step (i.e., the party size is saved in the prompt for a location  and the location is saved in the prompt for date). I would like to save the user's input in the corresponding validation step. This would remove the entanglement between requests and allow me to reorder the questions without making a lot of extraneous changes. It would also allow me to use the same validator for questions of the same type.

How do I access the `WaterfallStepContext` from the Prompt Validator? This would allow me to save the user's input once I determined that it was valid. In addition, the `ChoicePrompt` is supposed to take a Prompt Validator as well but I can't seem to get that to work. It seems to have built-in validation but I would also like to save the user's input there as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not recommended to store any state when performing validation of a prompt value. Instead it should be the responsibility of the caller of the prompt to do something with that value. Specifically, when using `WaterfallDialog`, the pattern that is recommended is that the "next" step is always responsible for storing the result of the previous step.

So imagine having a number prompt that ensures a value between 1 and 100 is picked:

```cs
Add(new NumberPrompt<int>("myNumberPrompt", async (pvc, ct) => pvc.Succeeded && pvc.Recognized.Value > 1 && pvc.Recognized.Value < 100);
```

And then some waterfall steps that utilize that prompt:

```cs
private async Task<DialogTurnResult> FirstStep(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    return await stepContext.PromptAsync("myNumberPrompt", new PromptOptions { Prompt = MessageFactory.Text("Please pick a number between 1 and 100") }, cancellationToken);    
}

private async Task<DialogTurnResult> SecondStep(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
   // Get the result of the previous step which will be the value from the NumberPrompt<int>
   var chosenNumber = (int)stepContext.Result;

   // Store the value into the WaterfallStepContext's Values dictionary
   stepContext.Values["ChosenNumber"] = chosenNumber;

   await stepContext.Context.SendActivityAsync($"Ok, {chosenNumber}, got it.");

   // ... more code here, maybe prompt for other values, whatever ...
}
```

Comment: The recommended approach like the sample implies that the question set will be small and that you will have one function for each question, in spite of the fact that all the functions will be doing pretty much the same thing. Is there something inherently wrong with having one function for all questions and looking up the prompt based on the step? From a maintenance standpoint, I don't like writing lots of very similar functions.

Comment: I don't disagree with you at all and certainly I could see you being able to establish some kind of abstract implementation of your own on top of this based on what you're describing, but it's not in the box.

Comment: Does that mean that from the validation function I don't have access to the WaterfallStepContext? Without that, I can't write a general purpose validation.

Comment: You don't have access to it directly. I could tell you how to hack through and access it, but honestly I don't want to waste your time because that would be completely fragile because you'd be accessing the raw, _internal_ state of the `WaterfallDialog` implementation which is subject to change and, thus, such a hack could break tomorrow.